# What is the minimum level one can feasibly reach the 3rd challenge chamber in Nier's DLC?

Tags: nier

What is the minimum level one can feasibly reach the 3rd "World of the Recycled Vessel" challenge chamber in *Nier*? I ask because the 3rd chamber of the DLC is supposed to have enemies that have a higher drop rate of `Titanium Alloy` than the robots in the Junk Heap.

At the time of asking, I am around level 13 and die in 2 hits in the first challenge chamber.

Comment: This also depends on your difficulty setting, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The 1st Door can be cleared right after starting part 2 of the game when you are in your low 20s. It seems the key is to have a strong weapon from that part of the game.
- The 2nd Door will kill you in 1 or 2 hits in the first chamber at that level. It can be cleared easily in the mid-20s.
- The 3rd Door can be cleared in the late 20s with a suitably upgraded weapon. Just be careful of the 3rd boss on the bridge, it can kill in 1 hit!

Comment: What difficulty level is this based on?